# Horizontal auto-layout constraint

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

In a subclass of UITableViewCell, I am trying to use auto layout.

Here is what I want to do :
[image: layout]

Here is my code which doesn't work : **only one view is shown**

```
import Foundation

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    func configureCell() {

        backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

        let redColorView = UIView()
        redColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        redColorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let blueColorView = UIView()
        blueColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        blueColorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(blueColorView)
        addSubview(redColorView)

        let viewsDictionary = ["blue":blueColorView,"red":redColorView]

        let layout = NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0)

        let horizontalContraint:[NSLayoutConstraint] = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-10-[blue]-10-[red]-10-|", options: layout, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

        let verticalContraint_1:[NSLayoutConstraint] = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-10-[blue]-10-|", options: layout, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

        let verticalContraint_2:[NSLayoutConstraint] = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-10-[red]-10-|", options: layout, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

        self.addConstraints(verticalContraint_1)
        self.addConstraints(verticalContraint_2)
        self.addConstraints(horizontalContraint)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do ASCII art but way to long (and ugly)

Comment: are you set on using `constraintsWithVisualFormat`? I could probably figure this out but never used that before

Comment: Have you tried setting a constraint to make the two views have equal widths? I'm it familiar with setting constraints programmatically, but this would be really easy with the `InterfaceBuilder`.

Comment: I've just figured out that setting "|-10-[blue(50)]-10-[red]-10-|" or "|-10-[blue(red)]-10-[red]-10-|" works. I think a size should be set for one of the views ?

Comment: When the view loads, do you have any output in the console about conflicting constraints?

Comment: no, no conflicting constraints

Comment: I believe you are only supposed to let one of those views to size according to the space remaining in the superview. So if you say make the width of red = blue, and let blue auto size to fit it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your horizontal constraints are ambiguous. They are insufficient to resolve to exactly one layout. So, the system has to pick arbitrarily from among the possibilities.

In particular, `|-10-[blue]-10-[red]-10-|` doesn't specify how wide `blue` and `red` should be. Assuming the superview is wider than 30 points, any number of solutions are possible. `blue` could be 0 width and `red` could be the superview's width minus 30. Or vice versa. Or anything in between. The only effective constraint on the two subviews' widths is that they add up to the superview's width minus 30. Since you say that only one is visible, presumably the other has been assigned 0 width.

As you've noticed, you can explicitly constrain the width one of the subview or you can specify that they have equal width to each other (or some other ratio).

If the views had intrinsic size, or if they had subviews with intrinsic size and their widths were constrained based on their subviews, then things like content-hugging and compression-resistance priorities would come into play. But plain `UIView`s like you're using have no intrinsic size, so they don't.